# NPM unable to read file

Tags: node.js, file-io, npm

I have written a NPM module. which needs to read a file. While creating NPM module I have placed a file in same directory with .js file and used

```
var file = './sqlmap_config.json';
```

This files gets included well when I use the code standalone. When I create NPM module, this file is looked up in parent directory where NPM module is installed and code fails.

Do I need to hard code it to

```
var file = './node_modules/module/sqlmap_config.json';
```

Or there is any other way to accomplish this

Comment: what is your npm module path ? './node_modules/yourmodule' or './node_modules/module/yourmodule'

Comment: It is './node_modules/mymodule/'

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to want to use something like :

```
var file = __dirName + '/sqlmap_config.json';
```

https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#modules_dirname